# Canon 85 1.2 II - Is it possible AF works and MF doesn't?

Tags: canon

I understand this lens uses a fly by wire system, Electronically telling the camera the focus rings position and focusing accordingly. My friend is saying his lens only works in AF mode, will not focus in MF. Could this be possible or is he doing it wrong?

Comment: The cameras Autofocus works perfect. Can go from the closest metering to infinity and snap a photo. Manual focus does not work, it sort of makes the focus rotate sometimes, but it's completely random like it's searching back and forth, just by spinning the focus dial

Comment: what am i missing here.  manual focus is manual.   You physically turn the the focus ring, thereby moving the glass elements in the lens, until the subject of choice is in focus.  why would the camera be doing anything to the lens when you have turned off the auto focus.?

Comment: @Alaskaman some full-time MF lenses use an electronic MF ring - essentially it's a control input to the lens motor circuit.  It's easy to check: turn the camera off (or take the battery out), look through the viewfinder and turn the focus dial in MF mode.  Does anything change? My long sigma has this, and its the "fly-by-wire" the OP mentions

Comment: This lens does use focus-by-wire. Spinning the focus ring will not adjust the focus without metering power to the lens.

In my case, I have metering power to the lens, but the Focus range does not respond to my adjustments. 

I'm looking for a solution to AF and no MF, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The camera has to be **turned on** *and* **metering activated** before the focus-by-wire system will function. A simple half press of the shutter button or a press of the AE Lock (*) button is enough to make Manual Focus possible with a focus-by-wire lens such as the Ef 85mm f/1.2 L II.

A good rule of thumb to use is to just look in the viewfinder. If the viewfinder is active, i.e. the display is lit showing shutter speed, aperture, ISO, etc. then focus-by-wire will be active as well. If the viewfinder is not active, i.e. the display is not lit showing shooting info, then focus-by-wire will not be active either.

If the Manual focus-by-wire does not work when the camera is not turned on or when the camera is turned on but the metering is not active this is perfectly normal and to be expected.

If the Manual focus-by-wire does not work when the metering is active then the lens is not acting normally. Any time the camera is on and the metering is active the manual focus-by-wire should be working properly, regardless of whether the lens is set to AF or to MF.

Comment: The camera works great, the focus-by-wire system works in Automatic focus mode flawlessly. The figures in the viewfinder work great, The figures in the viewfinder are independent of a lens even being attached.


However, my question is about the manual focus mode for my lens. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @e46Canon Then the lens is not operating properly within specifications. Moving the manual focus ring should control the movement of the focus elements anytime the metering is active in either AF or MF.

Comment: Correct.  The focus ring does not respond in AF or MF. A weird quirk, after taking a photo, it will listen for a half second in the correct direction of my turn.

Answer (score 0):

For the manual focus to work camera has to be switched on. If the camera is on and the lens is not focusing you need to have it checked.

Comment: Of course my camera is on when i'm trying to focus and take a picture. Thanks for the comment.